# LTspice error reading a downloaded model

Tags: ltspice, spice

I'm downloading a model for an n-channel MOSFET, the DMG6968U-7.  This is the SPICE code:

```
*SRC=DMG6968U;DI_DMG6968U;MOSFETs N;Enh;20.0V 6.50A 25.0mohms  Diodes Inc MOSFET
*SYM=POWMOSN
.SUBCKT DMG6968U   10 20 30
*     TERMINALS:  D  G  S
M1   1  2  3  3  DMOS L=1U W=1U
RD  10  1  10.9m
RS  40  3  1.62m
RG  20  2  33.7
CGS  2  3  119p
EGD 12  0  2  1  1
VFB 14  0  0
FFB  2  1  VFB  1
CGD 13 14  226p
R1  13  0  1.00
D1  12 13  DLIM
DDG 15 14  DCGD
R2  12 15  1.00
D2  15  0  DLIM
DSD  3 10  DSUB
LS  30 40  7.50n
.MODEL DMOS NMOS(LEVEL=3 VMAX=41.7k THETA=80.0m
+ ETA=2.00m VTO=0.900 KP=31.8)
.MODEL DCGD D (CJO=226p VJ=0.600 M=0.680)
.MODEL DSUB D (IS=27.0n N=1.50 RS=55.4m BV=20.0
+ CJO=176p VJ=0.800 M=0.420 TT=247n)
.MODEL DLIM D (IS=100U)
.ENDS
```

I cannot open the file with LTspice (if I try opening it from within LTspice, it does absolutely nothing;  if I drag-n-drop the file into the LTspice workspace, it gives me an "Encountered an Improper Argument" error).  Please help!

Actually, the above is not *exactly* the downloaded code — all of the `.model` directives were missing the closing bracket (parenthesis), so I added them, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: spice isn't spice, it was probably created for another spice

Comment: I have had trouble using Diodes Inc models in LT Spice, they will act as if the body diode is wrong way around. Once I was able to get an LTSpice model from them by asking on their their contact-us page, but YMMV...

Comment: Also, don't just open this file in LTSpice, put a `.include <file>` into your top-level design.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- the procedure that I've found easiest is to just create a symbol;  I open the file in LTspice (it gives me a "text editor with syntax highlight" window).  Then, right-click on the .subckt keyword, and the pop-up menu gives me the option to "Create a Symbol".  It then shows up in the [Autogenerated] folder when I click on the "Component" toolbar button to add components to the schematic.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- also:  I just tried downloading a model from a different manufacturer (the Si3442CDV from Vishay).  Same behaviour.  I actually wonder:  why are MOSFETs given as a .subckt and not simply a .model?  I see that there is a standard.mos file; however, all of the models are for VDMOS and not NMOS or PMOS.  No idea why, or what that VDMOS means.  Would it work if I copy the `.MODEL DMOS NMOS( ··· ` into that standard.mos file, adding the missing parameters such as Cgs and Cgd?  What other parameters might I need to add?

Comment: I just copied your subckt into LTspice and hooked up a symbol to it and grounded the source and gate and did a run. Seems okay, so far as it goes. No errors displayed.

Comment: @jonk -- I'll be damned!  Including the .subckt in the schematic (toolbar button .op, right?) does work.  The method I was trying is the symbol generation method shown in http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html.  Incidentally, the page http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html that shows the other method states that *this assumes the third-party model you’re adding follows popular pin order conventions*, and they say in case of doubt use the symbol generation method :-\

Comment: @Cal-linux All I did was (1) copy EESE text you provided; (2) open LTspice and create a new schematic; (3) Hit "s" to open a Spice dialog box and then ctrl-V to paste what I'd copied into it; (4) dropped that onto the schematic; (5) Hit F2 to call up the parts dialog and select the "nmos" device and drop that onto the schematic; (6) hover over the nmos part while holding "ctrl" down and right-click the mouse to get a "component attribute editor" dialog box; (7) change the Prefix to "X" and change the Value to "DMG6968U" and hit OK; (8) ground source and gate; (9) Try to run it.

Comment: @jonk -- yes, that's the same procedure I tried after reading your post/comment;  instead of "s", I used the .op toolbar button (rightmost button on the toolbar).  But I just checked, and it is equivalent to "s"  (the Edit sub-menu confirms they're equivalent).  And yes, it did seem to work on my side as well, even though the "Generate New Symbol" keeps failing.  Oh well --- worth keeping in mind for the future!

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the model file to the schema? Maybe you have not added the model correctly or have you selected the option?

You must add the model to the scheme as SPICE Directive.Add a n-channel MOSFET symbol and right click on the MOSFET with the Ctrl key pressed simultaneously. In the new window, you need to change the prefix, for example, to “X”, and Value to the value from the model. The model name can be found after the .SUBCKT directive.

You can find more details on my blog:

https://sigaris-electronics.eu/2018/11/ltspice-adding-an-element-model-to-the-schema/